# How to deal with user arguments with magit transients?

Tags: magit, transients

I understand the infix flags work. However, I'm not sure how best to work with argument inputs. I have read the docs as well as looked at some examples from the magit source code but it's still a little bit beyond me as I need some really basic examples to get me started:

Given these two functions:

```
(defun say-hi:fn (&optional args)
  (message "%s" (<read-args> args)))

(define-transient-command say-hi ()
  "Say Hi"
  ["Arguments"
   ("-g" "Greeting" "--greeting")
   ("-n" "Name" "--name")]
  ["Actions"
   ("H" "Hi" say-hi:fn)])
```

1. How do I customise the default Greeting to be `"Hello"` and the default Name to be `"World"`?
2. How do I define  to sample `<greeting>` and `<name>` from `args`?
3. How do I limit the selection of `<greeting>` to be one of `Hello`, `Hi` and `G'day`?
4. How do I hook up `<name>` to be read from another input source such as `counsel` or a form widget?